# My motor in my 2003 Honda 400EX Four Wheeler is making a ticking noise

Tags: engine, honda, noise, atv

It's not the lifters might be timing chain but don't know.

Comment: Can you add any more information to your question?  If you put some effort into your question chances are good that you will get a more comprehensive answer.  Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Comment: Where does the sound seem to come from? Under what conditions does it occur? Does it get louder or increase with RPM? Are there any conditions under which it does not occur? Does anything stand out about when it started (ie after a wreck, a long ride, or a particularly hot/cold/wet day?)

Answer (score 2):

**It's your valves or the cam chain**

If you have a ticking sound, those are your two options.

You haven't provided much data or info at all.

**Adjust your valves**

.004 inch clearance for your intake valves

.005 inch clearance for you exhaust valves

**OR**

Check your cam chain tensioner to ensure it's putting the proper tension on your cam chain.